# AFJSONRequestOperation delay in response

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, afnetworking

Requests with AFNetworking:

```
  NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    [queue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:1];
    [queue addOperation:request1];
    [queue addOperation:request2];
```

The request1 gets its response immediately after calling it.
But second request2 receives response with 14 or 16 seconds delay after calling it.

Server log shows that the request2 went there with 14-16 seconds delay from client time. and it responds immediately. so server should be right.

What it could be?

Comment: use wireshark or charlesproxy to grab a capture of it happening, that might provide a clue.

Answer (score 1):

You set the `maxConcurrentOperationCount` to 1 effectively making your queue serial. This means that only one operation runs at any time.

Probably the first operation (request1) takes 14-16 seconds.

If you want to run both requests at the same time increase the `maxConcurrentOperationCount`

Comment: it is not helping. the requests should perform sequentially. And the fist response went in milliseconds.

Comment: @phantom.dnepr If you need the requests to be run sequentially, you should use `NSOperation` dependencies, or create the second operation in the completion block of the first. Either way, more information would be required to understand what's going on in order to help you. Descriptions of what the requests are, logs of the responses coming through, that sort of thing.